# Getting Response Code 400 (syntaxe Error) when executing Post Methode

Tags: java, json, http, authorization

I'm trying to execute Post method for content creation using String as a Json Objec, but i'm getting 400.
According to Google, 400 is used when you have a syntaxe error.

Here is the Method that I have been using, used to work on another server the only thing that I have changed was the json object

Can anyone please help ?

```
 public int createJiraEmployee(Employee employee)throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, Exception {
            
            //prepare request     
            CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
            
            
            
      
                    
            String json = "{\"fields\":{\"project\":{\"key\":\"CHECK\"}"
                    + ",\"issuetype\":{\"name\":\"New Joiner Checklist\"},"
                    + "\"summary\":\"Checklist New Joiner Checklist\""
                    + ",\"description\":\"Please do all tasks related to HR Checklist\","
                    + "\"customfield_12721\":\"FirstnameTest\","
                    + "\"customfield_12722\":\"lastnametest\","
                    + "\"customfield_12723\":{\"value\":\"Employee\"},"
                    + "\"customfield_12732\":\"PRESALES CONSULTANT\","
                    + "\"customfield_12725\":\"1003148\","
                    + "\"customfield_12726\":{\"value\":\"Company Test\"},"
                    + "\"customfield_12685\":{\"value\":\"BUtest\"},"
                    + "\"customfield_12673\":{\"value\":\"Department test\"},"
                    + "\"customfield_12727\":{\"value\":\"IT\"},"
                    + "\"customfield_12667\":{\"name\":\"managerTest\"},"
                    + "\"customfield_12708\":\"2020-04-08\","
                    + "\"customfield_14000\":\"France\","
                    + "\"customfield_14001\":\"Teamtest\","
                    + "\"customfield_14002\":\"Team2test\"}}";
            
            SimpleDateFormat formatter= new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss z");
            
    
            try {
                json = URLEncoder.encode(json, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
                //ATTENTION ERREUR EXPRES 
                urlCreateEmployee +=  json ;
               
                
    
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(urlCreateEmployee);
               
               // String encodedAuth = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(auth.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                String encodedAuth = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(("username:password").getBytes());
                authHeaderValue = "Basic " + encodedAuth;
                httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", authHeaderValue);
               
       
                
                //call WS
                CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
                   
                //Get response 
              // String res = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                 int res  = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

Comment: Try copying `json` to a json formatter and see if there is an error.  But really, create a class to hold those fields, populate an instance, and then convert to a json string.

Comment: I'm just trying to test the connectivity with server first, thus, I have generated the json code by using https://tools.knowledgewalls.com/jsontostring